# How to display the Rich text in text template in Visual flow

Tags: visual-workflow, inputrichtext, richtext-notes

I am using the chatter post action in Visual flow. I am using the text template for displaying the message in salesforce.Whenver i am choosing rich text in text template.But it is always is disaplying the plain text in salesforce.

For example Rich text template in salesforce:

```
@{!Loop_element.Owner:User.Username}Account is deleted
```

Plain text template in salesforce:

```
<p><a href="@{!Loop_element.Owner:User.Username}" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">@{!Loop_element.Owner:User.Username}</a> Account is deleted.
```

Output is always displaying the chatter message in salesforce as plain text:

```
<p><a href="@{!Loop_element.Owner:User.Username}" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">@{!Loop_element.Owner:User.Username}</a> Account is deleted.
```

I dont want chatter message in salesforce as plain text.I want only Rich text value in salesforce.

This is really impacting so Much.I am choosing rich text in flow.But it is displaying as plain text.How to overcome this?please anyone guide me.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post so not sure if you got your answer, so this is for future researchers. I found the answer to this on an unofficalsf.com article.

Preventing HTML Tags From Being Saved in a Text Template Body Field
The only way to be sure that your flow metadata will not contain tags that would become visible if the text template was passed to a plain text consumer like the existing Send Email or Post to Chatter actions is to either:

1. Set the text template to Plain Text before entering any text or
2. Change the text template to Plain Text and hand-remove any resulting tags that become visible.

https://unofficialsf.com/flow-rich-text-html-and-text-templates-winter-20-update/

This worked for me.